# Show error once per upload

Tags: php

I've run into a tricky situation.

I have an image upload field and depending on if there's any errors (not right file type, file size too large, duplicate upload) it will throw an error and not let them upload it and it displays a bootstrap alert notifying them.

However, this alert stays there on page refresh or even if they navigate to another page of the site and come back, the alert comes back.

I've tried exporting the error variable to javascript and having it empty after a certain amount of time or when the user clicks the X to close the alert but none of that has worked, the alert still comes back when they navigate back to the page.

I don't think cookies would help because after the image is uploaded the page refreshes to show the picture so if I set the cookie then the page refreshes the browser would see the cookie is set and delete the array before the user can even see it.

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $message[] = "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $message[] = "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $message[] = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        $message[] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $uImageLink = "images/" . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            try
        {
            $DB_host = "localhost";
            $DB_user = "none of";
            $DB_pass = "your";
            $DB_name = "business";

            $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
            $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `Image` = :uImage WHERE `Id` = :uId");

            $stmt->bindparam("uId", $uId);
            $stmt->bindparam("uImage", $uImageLink);

            $stmt->execute();

            $user->redirect('http://mysite/yo');
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        } else {
            $message[] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
}
```

Then in my HTML down below:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($message); $i++) {
        echo '
            <div class="alert alert-danger">'. $message[$i] . '</div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: code code code code code

Comment: code code code code code

Comment: code code code code code coming up

Comment: Which alerts are firing? Looks to me like the wrong image type would always fire, regardless of whether an image was actually uploaded or not.

Comment: @BobNocraz Well depending if they run into errors or not. The code for the errors is fine, if there's none it wont fire. However once the error populates the array I can't get it to leave the page, even if they leave and come back.

Comment: Where's the Javascript?

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question; if it's helpful please upvote, and if it answers your question please mark it as accepted. Otherwise let me know what's wrong with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling all this code unless there's actually been an upload.

Let's take a look at selected statements from your code, assuming the user has not uploaded an image:

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
// you should've seen an undefined index error in your logs, and $target_file now equals "images/"
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// "images/" doesn't have an extension so this is empty

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    // an empty string isn't going to match any of those
    $message[] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// oh look, $message is populated now!

for ($i = 0; $i < count($message); $i++) {
    echo '
        <div class="alert alert-danger">'. $message[$i] . '</div>
    ';
}
```